# Why readline giving an extra line?

Tags: java

I have been working on this code since 3/4 hours. Now I feel I can not fix it if some one does not help me. This is UVA 10082.There is always a extra newline comes when I put input.Which is not desirable.

When I run this at UVA..always says wrong answer.But i checked on my pc, it is fine.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class WERTYU {

public static void main(String args[]) {
    char keyboard[][] = {
        {'`', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '0', '-', '='},
        {'Q', 'W', 'E', 'R', 'T', 'Y', 'U', 'I', 'O', 'P', '[', ']', '\\'},
        {'A', 'S', 'D', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'J', 'K', 'L', ';', '\''},
        {'Z', 'X', 'C', 'V', 'B', 'N', 'M', ',', '.', '/'}
    };
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    while (in.hasNext()) {
        String line = in.nextLine();
        char letter[];
        letter = line.toCharArray();
        for (int i = 0; i < letter.length; i++) {
           //if (letter[i] == ' ')System.out.print("");
            if (letter[i] == 'Q' || letter[i] == 'A' || letter[i] == 'Z' || letter[i] == '`') {
                System.exit(0);
            } else {
                for (int m = 0; m < 4; m++) {

                    for (int n = 1; n < keyboard[m].length; n++) {

                        if (letter[i] == keyboard[m][n]) {
                            letter[i] = keyboard[m][n - 1];
                        }

                    }

                }
                System.out.print(letter[i]);

            }

        }

    }

 }
}
```

input:

```
O S, GOMR YPFSU/
```

Output:

```
[new Line]
I AM FINE TODAY.
```

There is a bug suppose you give the input `WSA`. The Program should terminate as Q A Z and ` can not be input.but it is giving

```
 QA
```

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem: http://ideone.com/FShpWL

Comment: Yes I can see that.It is working there but why it is a wrong answer?Does stackoverflow community is prohibited to help to fix specific problem?

Comment: Quite the contrary. But if it's a problem that can't be reproduced, how can we solve it? It could be a bug in the particular environment you're working in - we have no way of knowing.